# Reading from postgres and using data in expressjs

Tags: json, postgresql, select, express, ejs

I have working connection with postgres using pg node-module. Since i'm new to javascript i need help me in reading the data from the db and display it through ejs template.
code snippet:

```
ws.post('/select',function(req,res){
var vill = req.body.Inputvillage;
pg.connect(conString,function(err,client,done){
if(err){
return console.error('Could not connect to postgres' , err);
}
var results = [];
var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM  \"Area_info\" WHERE \"Folder_Name\" = $1",[vill],function(err,result){
query.on('row', function(row) {
        results.push(row);
    });
query.on('end', function() {
        done();
        return res.json(results);
    });  
  });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM  \"Area_info\" WHERE \"Folder_Name\" = $1",[vill],function(err,result){
query.on('row', function(row) {
        results.push(row);
    });
query.on('end', function() {
        done();

view_data = JSON.stringify(results);
//        return res.json(results);
     res.render('template',{ view_data:'view_data');   // here template is the name of your ejs file

    });  
  });
```

After that you can use in your ejs file like :

```
<select style="width:15%;" required="required" name="categ" >
                                  <option style="width:15%;" value="">Select Category</option>
                                  <% for(var d=0;d<view_data.length;d++)
                                    {  %>
                                  <option style="width:20%;" name="category" value=<%= view_data[d].name %>><%= view_data[d].name %></option>
                                  <% } %>
                                </select>
```

Here **name** assume that your column name.

and dont forget to set :   `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`   in your main file

Comment: what is doc[] here..??

Comment: by the way..also console.log(view_data) is returning undefined.

Comment: I do this with mongoDB so I do not need to parse it into json.  Is your query returning data

Comment: try now I made some changes.

Comment: hey i'm unable to access the key-value if use stringify. The var is accessible to template but not the key-value pair. I can only display the whole json as a string

Comment: sory i am not able to understand. what do you want to say ? please edit question or elaborate little bit more.

Comment: i am able to access the whole view_data as it contains the whole json as a string like--[ { "key" : "value"}], but i'm unable to access the view_data[d].key or view_data[d][key] in the template , it shows undefined if i try. May be it is due to stringify. Please help its urgent.

Comment: You need to pass the data of on more query  `select column_name from information_schema.columns where
table_name='table_name`    then use it as a key;